# Rails: controller, view and helper life cycles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder if there is any doc on that. I believe it is helpful to know when those objects get created and destroyed and whether they are re-used (like Java servlets). Particularly, I am wondering about helpers. I assume a new controller instance is created for every new request, and the same is true for views but not for helpers. In his [tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book) Michael Hartl uses SessionsHelper to store the current user, which makes me think helper lifetime is bound to the session. Is this correct? Then technically I can use helpers to store session info, right?

Comment: I'm interested, if you find anything on your side I would appreciate for you to drop a message here. This being said, I would bet that helpers (if they are kept between requests) won't be thread safe and perhaps not isolated between session.

Answer (score 3):

The basic flow goes like this:

```
(request) -- Rack stuff -- Controller instance -- View instance -- (response)
```

Any instance variables you set in the Controller are made available to the View. Those are threadsafe. Class variables, on the other hand, are not threadsafe.

Helpers are Modules, not Classes, so they aren't (can't be, really) instantiated. Instead, they're mixed into the View instance that evaluates your templates. Again, instance variables are threadsafe, class variables aren't.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking is that helper methods, as with every other part of a Rails app, is created & destroyed with each request

You have to remember the helper methods will not "store" any session data - they'll only call the [session cookies](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark) to display the relevant data:

> Most applications need to keep track of certain state of a particular
>   user. This could be the contents of a shopping basket or the user id
>   of the currently logged in user. Without the idea of sessions, the
>   user would have to identify, and probably authenticate, on every
>   request. Rails will create a new session automatically if a new user
>   accesses the application. It will load an existing session if the user
>   has already used the application.
>
> A session usually consists of a hash of values and a session id,
>   usually a 32-character string, to identify the hash. Every cookie sent
>   to the client's browser includes the session id. And the other way
>   round: the browser will send it to the server on every request from
>   the client. In Rails you can save and retrieve values using the
>   session method:

This demonstrates, to me at least, that every time you load a "helper", it's really relying on the user's stored data (particularly for the session). This means that although it may appear that a helper's lifecycle may extend beyond each request, it's really just relying on the data provided

Having said that, I need to read up on how to make this threadsafe etc, as per `benjamin sinclaire`'s comment